# hello test for spring mvc getting requested resoursces is not available

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

spring mvc helloworld writning code but getting error of Requested resourses is not avilable .i am posting here webxml,servlet context and application context code and controller `
web.xml

```html
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
      version="3.0">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>  
  
  <context-param>
  <param-name>ApplicationContext</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  
  
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
 
  
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping> 
  
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.requestcontextlistener</listener-class>
</listener>
</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
 
 <context:annotation-config />
 <context:component-scan base-package="com" />
 <mvc:annotation-driven />
 <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />
 
 <bean  id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp BasicDataSource">
 <!-- <property name="DriverClassName" class="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" /> -->
 <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
 <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/spring_test"/>
 <property name="username" value="root" />
 <property name="password" value="" />
 
 </bean>
 
 <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" >
 <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
 <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.entities"></property>
 <property name="hibernateProperties">
 <!-- <props key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</props> -->
    <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">spring-test</prop>
                <prop key="format_sql">true</prop>
              <prop key="use_sql_comments">true</prop>
               <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
            </props>
 </property>
 
 </bean>
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
 <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
 
 </bean>
 
</beans>
```

springMvcServlet.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
 
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
 <property name="viewResolver" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolve" />
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
 </bean>
 
 
 
 </beans>
```

here is Controller

```html
package com.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
@Controller
/*@RequestMapping(value="/users")*/
public class UserController {
 
 @RequestMapping( value="/hello", method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView getPage(){
  ModelAndView view= new  ModelAndView("hello");
  return view;
 }

}
```

hello is my jsp page hello.jsp in views folder
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIzDO.png)

after rumming in server i got the error "type Status report

message /TestSpring/

description The requested resource is not available."

Comment: Which URL are you trying to access? Do you have any controller mapped to that URL?

Comment: Can you output the exact error message ( as an image if possible)

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.request.requestcontextlistener

Answer (score 0):

In your ***web.xml*** param name for **context-param** is not correct.
It should be **contextConfiguration**. Change it to this

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```